# Groupyby count with condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I am struggling with the last line of the code attached below. In the final line I am seeking to get the count of all 'PM_Temp' that are equal to or less than 10, but I do not know how to write. Any help would be much appreciated

```
df1 = df.groupby(['City', 'year'])\
  .agg(Avg_Duration = ('duration', 'mean'),
        Max_Duration = ('duration', 'max'),
        Min_Duration = ('duration', 'min'),
        Ave_AM_Temp = ('AM_Temp', 'mean'),
        Max_AM_Temp = ('AM_Temp', 'max'),
        Min_AM_Temp = ('AM_Temp', 'min'),
        Ave_PM_Temp = ('PM_Temp', 'mean'),
        Max_PM_Temp = ('PM_Temp', 'max'),
        Min_PM_Temp = ('PM_Temp', 'min'),
        PM_Temp_10_or_less = (('PM_Temp', (<=10).count())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda function here:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['City', 'year'])\
  .agg(Avg_Duration = ('duration', 'mean'),
        Max_Duration = ('duration', 'max'),
        Min_Duration = ('duration', 'min'),
        Ave_AM_Temp = ('AM_Temp', 'mean'),
        Max_AM_Temp = ('AM_Temp', 'max'),
        Min_AM_Temp = ('AM_Temp', 'min'),
        Ave_PM_Temp = ('PM_Temp', 'mean'),
        Max_PM_Temp = ('PM_Temp', 'max'),
        Min_PM_Temp = ('PM_Temp', 'min'),
        PM_Temp_10_or_less = ('PM_Temp', lambda x: x.le(10).sum())
```

Comment: Thanks that was wonderful. Is it possible to add another condition, like this:
PM_Temp_10_or_less = ('PM_Temp', lambda x: x.le(10).sum() and 'Day' == 'Mon)

Comment: You can't, since named agg only sees/applies on one column at a time. You need another groupby object.

Comment: Perhaps then, an idea could be to reset the index, and then add new column applying conditions?